# Adjective for "doesn't need to be explained/justified"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an adjective that means "doesn't need to be justified" as in:

> His actions, which don't need to be justified.
>
> His ??? actions.

The person who makes the actions will never be held accountable for them, no matter how good or bad. The majority of the actions by all people will be acceptable but no consequences will happen to an individual who makes harmful actions. Imagine if everyone could literally *get away with murder*. Perhaps most people would never murder anyone, but a few people would. The families of the victims would be upset, but the rest of society wouldn't care because the system works most of the time, i.e. people can be trusted not to murder.

Perhaps another way of describing it is an abuse of privileges, or **actions which are free to be abused**, because you don't believe that anyone will.

I've looked in my thesaurus (full Macquarie) but the closest I've come up with is *unjustifiable* (can't be justified) or *carte blanche* (very close, but a noun).

I'm aware that nouns can be used as adjectives, so perhaps *His carte blanche actions*, but I would prefer a straight adjective, if one exists.

Comment: I think @BenjaminHarman has given a good answer, but if you can explain what you are looking for more precisely, for example by describing what is justified, or one or more similar examples, it may help draw additional choices. I think the condition of "not needing to be justified" could be interpreted in a number of subtle but relevant different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unaccountable**

> not required to explain actions or decisions - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unaccountable)

This takes into consideration your note about the person taking the action not being held accountable while others suffer negative consequences.

Answer (score 2):

[Irreproachable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/irreproachable?s=t) is an adjective that means that.  It means that his actions don't need to be justified, that they are beyond reproach. Another word you might use would be [unimpeachable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unimpeachable?s=t).